# What is the correct order of mysqli_stmt functions, if any

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

The code below does of course a valid query, but I decided to remove it to make it easier and I don't imagine it being necessary

The following code works without `mysqli_stmt_execute()`

```
$query = mysqli_prepare($db, 'SELECT query');

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query, 'i', $int);
mysqli_stmt_store_result($query);
if (mysqli_stmt_num_rows($query) >= 0)
{
     echo 'test';
}
```

The following also works, with `mysqli_stmt_execute()` before `mysqli_stmt_bind_result`

```
$query2 = mysqli_prepare($db, 'SELECT query');

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query2, 'i', $int);
mysqli_stmt_execute($query2);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($query2, $result);
mysqli_stmt_fetch($query2);
mysqli_stmt_close($query2);
```

So what is the correct order, if any? Will some of the `mysqli_stmt_` functions execute the query if it hasn't already been done?

Comment: The first code shouldn't work. You have to call `mysqli_stmt_execute()` to perform the query, there's no way around it.

Comment: If you don't execute the query, `mysqli_stmt_num_rows()` just returns `0`. You don't get any error, but the code doesn't really work.

Comment: sorry you're right. the value I was expecting is 0 so it threw me off. thank you.